# Can Facebook SDK allow for iOS app (linked with a facebook app) to post directly to a particular page?

Tags: facebook, ios6, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am trying to make an iOS app integrated with the Facebook SDK that allows the user to post directly to a facebook group page and receive updates directly from the group page through the app, as an alternative to the facebook app.

I know that the Facebook dialog class in the latest SDK allows us to share a status directly to one's wall but I have yet to find a way to post it to a page other than the user's wall. Is there a way to gain access to a facebook group page and retrieve the posts from the page and also post directly to it?